Transform xy in a 2d plane to increase distance
I have N points in a 2d plane bounded region (0,1).
I want to transform them such that distance between two points is increased proportional to how close they are to center horizontal line, (similar to zoom by a cylindrical lens)
Transformed points should preferably be in the same region (0,1)
I tried the following

def fisheye_distortion(x, y,):

    x, y = x.copy(), y.copy() 

    x_c = x - 0.5 

    y_d = np.abs(y - 0.5)  # distance from center along y_axis

    x_c *= (1 + np.e ** - y_d)

    x_c += 0.5

    return x_c, y 


But it's not even close
